# copy and pase only non empty cells to same range

Tags: excel, vba

i have two workbooks- workbook 1 have own datas-  and workbook2 have alot of data- the range that have data  in workbook2 may change during days,it is not constant . i wanna copy non empty data from (A1:last row last cloumn that have content)    in wokrbook2 to same range in workbook1-   i wanna empty cells not to be copied from workbook2 to workbook1.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Copy()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Set the name of sheet2
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set the name of sheet1

lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Sheet1 'Find last row in column A, for sheet 1


For i = 1 To lrow
    If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, "A").Value) Then ws2.Cells(i, "A").Value = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
Next i
End Sub
```